# Checkbox behavior after accessing a post method in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have a view page in my rails app where there is a form with some fields and a submit button to show a chart (from highcharts). That submit button leads to a post method.

On my chart there is a checkbox to show/hide y axis:

```
$('#showY').click(function () {
    if ($('#showY').is(':checked')) {  
  $('#container').highcharts().yAxis[0].update({
        labels: {
          enabled: true
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Y Axis'
        }
      });
    } else {
  $('#container').highcharts().yAxis[0].update({
        labels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        }
      });
    }
});

<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <input id="showY" type="checkbox"></input>
     <%= t('show_y_axis') %>
</div>
```

I marked the checkbox and saw the y axis and then I changed some fields in the form and pressed a submit again. Chart reloads but a checkbox is still marked as checked and y axis is not shown. 
Please help me to uncheck a checkbox after pressing a submit button.

P.S. I'm a newbie so don't judge hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell jquery to mark checkbox when page loads using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($('#showY').is(':checked'))
 {
   $('#container').highcharts().yAxis[0].update({
    labels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Y Axis'
    }
  });
 }
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Do I need to add this code somewhere or change my code?

Comment: you need to add this code in you file..so when page gets load and if checkbox is checked, x-axis will be visible.